# cut the string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

cut the string from last '/' to '.html'
I have a string like that

```
"/Views/GS/stockView.html"
```

My need the name "stockView"
How can I cut the name from a string?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = "/Views/GS/stockView.html";
a.split('/').pop().split(".")[0];
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z6gjanvv/)**

Answer (score 2):

use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) method, like

```
var str = "/Views/GS/stockView.html";
var slashPos = str.lastIndexOf('/');
var dotPos = str.indexOf('.', slashPos + 1);
var result = str.substring(slashPos + 1, dotPos);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using RegExp:

```js
var view = function(str) {
  return str.match(/\/(\w*)\./)[1];//finds a word between `/` and `.`
};

console.log(view("/Views/GS/stockView.html"));
console.log(view("/Views/fs/inventView.html"));
console.log(view("/Views/fs/p1/showView.jsp"));
console.log(view("/Views/fs/p2/showView123.aspx"));
```

```html
Open console
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var msg = "/Views/GS/stockView.html";
var startIndex = -1;
var endIndex=-1;
var length = msg.length;
for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (msg[i] == '/'){
       startIndex=i+1;
       break;
  }
  if(msg[i]==".")
    endIndex=i;
}

console.log(msg.substr(startIndex,endIndex-startIndex));
```

Or try this

```
var msg = "/Views/GS/stockView.html";
var split=msg.split("/");
split=split[split.length-1].split(".");
console.log(split[0]);
```